# How to import jQuery DataTables into Grails 2.4.4

Tags: jquery, datatables, asset-pipeline, grails-2.4

I have a Grails 2.4.4 app and am trying to implement a GSP that leverages a [jQuery DataTable](https://www.datatables.net/). I see there is an *old* [DataTable plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/jquery-datatables) but it looks unmaintained and incompatible with Grails 2.x. Not to mention, there *ought* to be a way to simply include *any* JS lib in Grails without explicitly requiring a plugin for it.

Here's the `plugins` section of my `BuildConfig`:

```
plugins {
    build ":release:3.0.1"
    build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"

    compile "org.grails.plugins:gson:1.1.4"
    compile ":rest-client-builder:1.0.3"
    compile ":yammer-metrics:3.0.1-2"

    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
    runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    runtime ":resources:1.2.14"
    compile ":cache-headers:1.1.7"

    compile ":rest-client-builder:1.0.3"
    compile ":export:1.6"
    compile ":standalone:1.2.3"
    compile ":cache-headers:1.1.7"
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.3'

    runtime ":resources:1.2.14"
    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.15"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
}
```

For reasons outside the scope of this quesiton, I *can't* remove or change any existing declarations in the `plugins` section, but I can add to them. I've heard that something called the "assets pipeline" is the new cool way of adding JS libs to a Grails app, but all the literature I can find on this pipeline is vague and high-level. And I can't find any real world concrete examples of using this pipeline to include DataTables in a Grails app.

The "*Hello World!*" version of a DataTable seems to be this:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
        </tr>

        ...lots of more rows
    </tbody>
</table>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

So I ask: **How go I get the (above) "Hello World" DataTable running inside a GSP?** What *specific* configs, plugins, etc. do I need to wire up to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your DataTable js files are saved in this directory web-app\js, you can use this Grails tag in your view where you need a DataTable.

```
<g:javascript src="jquery.datatables.min.js" />
```

Similarly, you can get your required css file as such

```
<g:external dir="css" file="jquery.datatables.css" />
```

once those the required files are loaded, you can call the jQuery function

```
<g:javascript>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
    } );
</g:javascript>
```